# Can I make an exception for the manifest merger replace tag?

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest-merging

This is my app’s manifest which I want to override the `android:supportsRtl` tag for all of my libraries

```
<application
android:name=".ApplicationClass"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:supportsRtl="false"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
tools:replace="android:icon,android:label,android:supportsRtl">
```

I have `5 libraries` which I want to replace the `android:supportsRtl=”false”` using `tools:replace`.

**But** there is `one library` which **I want to let it supportRtl**.

The question is that, **can I make an exception** for the library which needs `android:supportsRtl="true"` to actually support the RTL and leave the other libraries to be overridden by my app and stay `android:supportsRtl="false"`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently it is not possible. What you have to do is to come the other way around, i.e. specify what packages this markers should be applied to.

Make use of [marker selector](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#marker_selector) `tools:selector` specifying package names of other 4 libs you want the `tools:replace` to be applied to.

```
tools:selector="com.package.lib1, com.package.lib2"
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned by OP in comments, this will work only for `<permission>` tag.

Comment: Good point! But I think I end up with the merge conflict with the library manifest which stated in the manifest `android:supportsRtl="true"` :(

Comment: I can't understand the exact scenario, where a conflict would result. You have 5 modules, and in selector you mention, that you want to override merging rules for 4 of them. The fifth one would just come with the value it had. Why would it conflict?

Comment: It turned out that `Selector` marker is defined on `permision` tag and not on `application` tag. Doing this fails build.

Comment: Take a deeper look at your link from developers site: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#marker_selector

Comment: `<permission android:name="permissionOne"
    tools:node="remove"
    tools:selector="com.example.lib1">`